# Netbeans 8.2 RTF copy/paste plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins

Im looking for an rtf plugin to copy and paste formatted code from netbeans 8.2. I can only find up to 8.1 and need to copy the formatted code for a project.

Comment: What's the problem with copying code and then formatting it again?

Comment: Its about 1000 lines of code

Comment: IDEs have the handy feature of formatting your code for you. It's not a manual process. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: There was an update it seems:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/72681/rtf-copy-paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/72681/rtf-copy-paste) is a link for Netbeans 8.2 RTF plugin, the previous releases are not compatible with Netbeans 8.2. The project is available at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/mimowo/rtfcopypaste), for any issue with this release go [here](https://bitbucket.org/mimowo/rtfcopypaste/issues?status=new&status=open). I have installed and it is working good for me.